# Angular js style changing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following piece of code:

```
$scope.books.Name =$scope.books.Name+ '  (Disposed)';
```

Html code is:
    
Hre it is binding the text. 
I want tp assign diffrent color to the r.h.s part of $scope.books.Name
How should i do it? I am new to angular js.
OP IS: Tax Disposed .
I want Tax color to be only changed.

Comment: Please provide your code, HTML/AngularJS. The given info is insufficient to understand the problem and see what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Without complete code it's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve (maybe my English is weak but what do you meah with r. h. s.?), anyway maybe ngClass (and a custom CSS class) could be useful?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use `ng-class`. Here is an working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.books = [{
    author: 'Dickens',
    title: 'A Christmas Carol',
    disposed: false
  },
  {
    author: 'Twain',
    title: 'The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn',
    disposed: true
  }];
});
```

```css
.disposed {
  color: red;
}

th, td {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as C">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="book in C.books">
        <td>
          {{book.author}}
        </td>
        <td>
          <span ng-class="{disposed: book.disposed}">
            {{book.title}}
          </span>
          <span ng-if="book.disposed">
            &nbsp;(Disposed)
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```